# UV map and re texturing it

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I have an object that is inside a game and I have its UV map inside the game and on my PC.

What I want is to take that UV map and make textures depending on it so when I upload this textures back to the game it fits, so can I use the UV map I have on my computer without the having the object on my computer (or having both the object and the UV map inside Blender) to make a whole new texture.

I know how to do it when I have unwrapped the object inside blender but what I missing here is how to do it without having an object only UV map to make a textured map out of it I also have the normal map and other maps but no need to blend them on my computer since I can blend them inside the game already.

I have a UV map without an object and I want to make a new textures depending on that UV map so the new textures fit right on the object how I can do that?

Can I create other maps out of a UV map? using the software tools and my imagination without having an object to do the changes on the bake to a map?

What I can and what I can't do? and if it can be made in other programs like maybe Photoshop if it can't be made inside Blender ?

PICS EDIT...

here that is what I have the UV map of an object but not the object itself because the object itself inside the game and can't be downloaded I can only download pics from the game 
[image]

and that what I want to do I want to take that UV map and add texture to it like this 
[image]

I think it can be made with paint if I want just paint but what I want to do is adding a real texture with dots maybe or something not just coloring one area

here is more pics

texture like this 
[image]
[image]

not just colors like this

[image]
[image]
[![enter image description here][7]][7]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You want to do what is called 'game modding' as there they do take a model out of a game with its UV mapping and its textures that all align to that UV map and then they repaint the color or diffuse map and repackage it to go back in the game.  Painting information is possible in Blender in texture paint mode, but baking normal maps means you need 3d information that will get you the correct map, sometimes meaning introducing a higher poly model to do that.Perhaps look this up and come back with better examples of what you need help on as a single question as this is a wide range of questions.

Comment: well I tried to search game modeling and it is a very big subject I will try and edit the question and add more some pics ... maybe pics will explain better than words

Answer (score 1):

Don't feel bad about understanding all of this, it can be very confusing and it takes a while to get.

There are a lot of bases to hit here, and they are all deep enough to be a full paying job in their own right.  Hopefully, this info should help you ask more targeted questions with this info, so here we go:

**UV Maps** are just a way of relating 2D information (like a picture) to a 3d object (such as a model). 
 [image: Example model/mapping] 
Blender can generate these for you by going into edit mode, selecting everything (<kbd>a</kbd>), and pressing <kbd>u</kbd> for the unwrap menu, and choosing "smart unwrap" (results are sub-optimal, but "good enough").  Unwrapping models are an art to themselves, because where cuts are added to the model to allow the UV's to be made flat can be noticeable.

Once you have a UV map, **textures** can be applied to your model.  The simplest one is **Diffuse**, as this the model's color (the rainbow example pictured above).  There are other maps that you may use that will affect how those colors are shown further, depending on renderer and shader, such as **Gloss**, **Emission**, **Specular**, or even **Transparency** (to name only a few).

A **Normal Map** is an extremely special kind of texture.  This is a way to fake geometric detail into a model that doesn't have the geometry itself to pull it off.  Someone usually does this in order to preserve detail from a high poly sculpt while still being able to use the model in a game or animate with.
[image: difference between sculpt, low poly, and lowpoly with normals]

You will usually know you are dealing with a Normal Map (sometimes referred to as a **Tangent Map**) if it is mostly purple with fluorescent reds and greens here and there.

[image: Normal map being used for color]

The usual way to generate a Normal Map is to take a high-poly model and bake on the details to a lower detailed model, Blender is capable of doing this.  There are also programs that let you draw directly on Normal maps, but as far as I know, Blender is not one of them.

Comment: yes I know that and I know how to do it when I have made the project from the beginning ... but I didn't knew I know change the normal maps with other softwares I will be searching for that for sure ... thank you sooo much for the info I needed that one ... and I will edit my question and add some pics to explain better what I have in mind